# Awk - Compare two files, match a field, merge both files

Tags: text, awk

Hey Guys I need some help here, 
my goal is to match find or match the first part of file1 within file2

File1:

```
\\tempcomputer\c$\test2;test folder;c:\test2
\\tempcomputer\c$\temp;temp folder;C:\temp
\\tempcomputer\c$\unavailablefolder;c:\unavailablefolder
```

File2:

```
\\tempcomputer\c$\test2\;2.777.768 Bytes;11/09/12;11/09/12
\\tempcomputer\c$\temp\;5.400.050.974 Bytes;10/09/12;11/09/12
Error: Invalid property element: \\tempcomputer\c$\unavailablefolder
```

Expected output:

```
\\tempcomputer\c$\test2;test folder;c:\test2;2.777.768 Bytes;11/09/12;11/09/12
\\tempcomputer\c$\temp;temp folder;C:\temp;5.400.050.974 Bytes;10/09/12;11/09/12
\\tempcomputer\c$\unavailablefolder;c:\unavailablefolder;Error: Invalid property element: \\tempcomputer\c$\unavailablefolder
```

---

I would like to compare for example from the first line of file1:

```
\\tempcomputer\c$\test2
```

search that on the second file, and concatenate both files, from file1

```
\\tempcomputer\c$\test2;test folder;c:\test2
```

and from file2

```
c:\test2;2.777.768 Bytes;11/09/12;11/09/12
```

So the first line would be:

```
\\tempcomputer\c$\test2;test folder;c:\test2;2.777.768 Bytes;11/09/12;11/09/12
```

Expected result for the first line:

```
\\tempcomputer\c$\test2;test folder;c:\test2;2.777.768 Bytes;11/09/12;11/09/12
```

Expected result for the second line:

```
\\tempcomputer\c$\temp;temp folder;C:\temp;5.400.050.974 Bytes;10/09/12;11/09/12
```

Expected result for the third line:

```
\\tempcomputer\c$\unavailablefolder;c:\unavailablefolder;Error: Invalid property element: \\tempcomputer\c$\unavailablefolder
```

Comment: For clarity, can you simplify the inputs and expected outputs? At least for me, it's unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I would like to compare for example from the first line of file1: \tempcomputer\c$\test2 search that on the second file, and concatenate both files, from file1 \tempcomputer\c$\test2;test folder;c:\test2 and from file2 c:\test2;2.777.768 Bytes;11/09/12;11/09/12. So the first line would be: \tempcomputer\c$\test2;test folder;c:\test2;2.777.768 Bytes;11/09/12;11/09/12

Comment: @Eduardo does the second file's, first part of the line, end up with `\;` ? or is that a typo ? ie for the first line, is it `\\tempcomputer\c$\test2\;2...` or `\\tempcomputer\c$\test2;2...` ?

Comment: That's correct is not a typo the first part of the 2nd line ends up with \;  for ie \tempcomputer\c$\test2\;2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is as *c00kiemon5ter* indicates a copy-paste error with the backslashes it's a simple matter of iterating through `File2` for each line in `File1`, I assume you want no output when no match is found.

*simple.awk*

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = ";" }

{ 
  l=$0
  first=$1
  while(getline < "File2") { 
    if(first == $1) {
      print l, $0
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Run with:

```
awk -f simple.awk File1
```

To allow an optional backslash at the end takes a bit more work, but most of the extra complexity can be moved to a function:

*more-work.awk*

```
function optional_end(s, c) {
  if(c == "")
    c = "\\"
  if(substr(s, length(s)) == c)
    s = substr(s, 1, length(s) - 1)
  return s
}

BEGIN { FS = OFS = ";" }

{ 
  l=$0
  first = optional_end($1)

  while(getline < "File2") {
    if(first == optional_end($1)) {
      print l, $0
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Run with:

```
awk -f more-work.awk File1
```

---

***edit by c00kiemon5ter*  :3**

revised *simple.awk*.
Works with `\;` first-field-line-endings and prints-joins the 3rd line too.

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = ";"; if( file == "") file = "File2" }

{ 
  l=$0
  first=$1
  while(getline < file) { 
    if((idx = index($0, first))) {
      if (idx == 1)
          $1 = l
      else
          $1 = l FS $0
      print
      break
    }
  }
}
```

***edit 2***

Input file can now be given as an option `-v file=SOME_FILE`; if none is given "File2" is used, e.g.:

```
awk -f simple.awk -v file=SOME_FILE File1
```

Comment: if you change `if(first == $1)` in _simple.awk_ to `if(first "\\" == $1) ` it will work as _more-work.awk_

Comment: also, he doesn't want to `print l, $0` but `print l, $2..$NF`. I will edit your answer to fix those in a new code block.

Comment: keep in mind that this still wont print/join the 3rd line. To do that, we should probably replace `if(first "\\" == $1)`. Will fix this now. Done ;)

Comment: btw, I hope it's ok to edit your answer with this. As I based my ideas on your script, I thought I'd just "fix" it in-place and not create another answer.. here's a +1 :P

Comment: No worries. Your final solution returns the result the OP listed, whilst mine only handle part of the problem and should probably be removed. It's up to you, correct this answer or post your own and I'll delete this one.

Comment: Is it possible to instead of having file2 specified on the awk script to be a parameter to be passed while running the script? 
Similar to this,
 awk -f simple.awk File1 File2

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there's no terminal backslash at the end of the paths in File2, the following:

```
join -t ';' <(sort File1) <(sort File2)
```

will output:

```
\\tempcomputer\c$\temp;temp folder;C:\temp;5.400.050.974 Bytes;10/09/12;11/09/12
\\tempcomputer\c$\test2;test folder;c:\test2;2.777.768 Bytes;11/09/12;11/09/12
```

Comment: :) that's what I had in mind, but the 3rd line wont match .. and it's not a typo :/

Comment: this also assumes that every line will match, doesn't it ? ie, if the 2nd file starts with an arbitary line that doesn't match anything in the 1st file, does `join` handle this (as in skips it and correctly joins starting from the 2nd line..) ?

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter: It prints matched lines and skips unmatched ones. There are options to print unmatched lines and other output control options.

Comment: Thanks, I tested it and as you said works but not with the third line. I will keep this in mind thanks